# How to integrate the following gamma distribution integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_0^1 \frac{a(\Gamma(a+b+1))}{(a+b)(\Gamma(a+1)+\Gamma(b))}x^a(1-x)^{b-1} dx$$
How to evaluate this integral? Obviously it is about gamma distribution.

Comment: If the integration is in $\text{d} x$ then it's trivial and you SHOULD be able to do it by yourself.

Comment: Actually this is a [beta integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).
 Also see the [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution).

Comment: @angryavian I believe the result will be a sort of HyperGeometric Function instead.

Comment: I am a bit confused by that? Without those "+1" in the top and bottom i would say that this would be equal to $a/(a+b)$

Comment: @mkropkowski actually there should be product and not a sum of Gammas in the denominator for that to happen.

Comment: OK nevertheless why those "+1" do not change anything (if we were to talk about a product)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terms which do not depend on $x$ can be ignored for the moment, and we are left calculating the integral:
$$
\int_0^1 x^a (1-x)^{b-1}
$$
but that is exactly a $\beta(a+1,b)=\frac{\Gamma(a+1)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b+1)}$.

Plugging that back into the equation gives us 
$$
\frac{a\Gamma(a+b+1)\Gamma(a+1)\Gamma(b)}{(a+b)(\Gamma(a+1)+\Gamma(b))\Gamma(a+b+1)}=\frac{a\Gamma(a+1)\Gamma(b)}{(a+b)(\Gamma(a+1)+\Gamma(b))}
$$

I do not see a simple way of simplifying this result.

Note that if we had a product of Gammas in the denominator instead of a sum we would have a further simplification to give $a/(a+b)$.